# LSTM in Keras Theano Exception Error

Tags: exception, keras, theano, lstm

I am trying to fit an LSTM model and my code crashes with this error. Can anyone suggest a way to resolve this?

Exception: ('The following error happened while compiling the node', Elemwise{Composite{Switch(LE(i0, i1), i1, i2)}}[(0, 0)](Shape_i{1}.0, TensorConstant{0}, TensorConstant{0}), '\n', 'Compilation failed (return status=1): g++.exe: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory\r. ', '[Elemwise{Composite{Switch(LE(i0, i1), i1, i2)}}[(0, 0)](, TensorConstant{0}, TensorConstant{0})]')

Comment: may be your version of g++ is new for the your current theanos version
You can install and use explicitly an older version of g++, or try to preload the system libstdc++

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be disappeared. Apparently something was wrong with mingw version. I tried the following in my anaconda prompt (You wont need a lot of these packages tho):

conda install numpy scipy mkl-service libpython m2w64-toolchain nose nose-parameterized sphinx pydot-ng